# Convert 2D List in 2D String Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I'm working with CSV but all the tutorials I've read use 2D Lists.

```
private void cargaCSV()
    {
        List<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();

        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(*my file*));
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            values.Add(line.Split(';'));
        }
    }
```

My problem is my project works with 2D String Array.

I tried the following:

```
    string [,]  Data = values.ToArray();
```

I want to convert the 2d list into 2d array

Comment: You're trying to get a `[,]`?

Comment: Do all lines have the same number of values?

Comment: Yes, all lines have the same number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the arrays have the same length, then you can do what you are doing and, after that, create and fill the array manually:

```
string[,] stringArray = new string[values.Count, values.First().Length]

for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    row = values[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.Length; j++)
        string[i,j] = row[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to typecast hard and old way.

Simply replace

```
string [,]  Data = values.ToArray();
```

With

```
var  Data = values.ToArray();
```

Now Data is two dimensional array of strings.